# why does JBPM shows an error when starting a user task?

Tags: jboss, jbpm, business-process-management

in JBPM after some REST API tasks a user task starts, after this user task another user task should start but an error occurred! there is no difference whether this new user task be empty or with parameters, after entering in the new user task this error occurres! would you please help me?

this is the error log:

17:16:54,444 ERROR [org.kie.server.remote.rest.jbpm.UserTaskResource] (default task-1264) Unexpected error during processing Unable to commit transaction: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to commit transaction

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445135335Z  at deployment.kie-server.war//org.drools.persistence.jta.JtaTransactionManager.commit(JtaTransactionManager.java:249)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445141119Z  at deployment.kie-server.war//org.jbpm.services.task.persistence.TaskTransactionInterceptor.execute(TaskTransactionInterceptor.java:92)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445146107Z  at deployment.kie-server.war//org.jbpm.services.task.persistence.TaskTransactionInterceptor.execute(TaskTransactionInterceptor.java:49)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445151073Z  at deployment.kie-server.war//org.drools.core.command.impl.AbstractInterceptor.executeNext(AbstractInterceptor.java:39)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445165957Z  at deployment.kie-server.war//org.drools.persistence.jta.TransactionLockInterceptor.execute(TransactionLockInterceptor.java:73)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445171565Z  at deployment.kie-server.war//org.drools.persistence.jta.TransactionLockInterceptor.execute(TransactionLockInterceptor.java:45)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445176573Z  at deployment.kie-server.war//org.drools.core.command.impl.AbstractInterceptor.executeNext(AbstractInterceptor.java:39)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445181425Z  at deployment.kie-server.war//org.drools.persistence.jpa.OptimisticLockRetryInterceptor.internalExecute(OptimisticLockRetryInterceptor.java:102)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445186356Z  at deployment.kie-server.war//org.drools.persistence.jpa.OptimisticLockRetryInterceptor.execute(OptimisticLockRetryInterceptor.java:83)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445191172Z  at deployment.kie-server.war//org.drools.persistence.jpa.OptimisticLockRetryInterceptor.execute(OptimisticLockRetryInterceptor.java:44)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445196065Z  at deployment.kie-server.war//org.drools.core.command.impl.AbstractInterceptor.executeNext(AbstractInterceptor.java:39)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445200829Z  at deployment.kie-server.war//org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.error.ExecutionErrorHandlerInterceptor.internalExecute(ExecutionErrorHandlerInterceptor.java:66)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445205753Z  at deployment.kie-server.war//org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.error.ExecutionErrorHandlerInterceptor.execute(ExecutionErrorHandlerInterceptor.java:52)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445212116Z  at deployment.kie-server.war//org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.error.ExecutionErrorHandlerInterceptor.execute(ExecutionErrorHandlerInterceptor.java:29)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445217319Z  at deployment.kie-server.war//org.drools.core.runtime.InternalLocalRunner.execute(InternalLocalRunner.java:37)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445222325Z  at deployment.kie-server.war//org.drools.core.runtime.InternalLocalRunner.execute(InternalLocalRunner.java:41)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445227301Z  at deployment.kie-server.war//org.jbpm.services.task.commands.TaskCommandExecutorImpl.execute(TaskCommandExecutorImpl.java:49)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445232045Z  at deployment.kie-server.war//org.jbpm.services.task.impl.command.CommandBasedTaskService.complete(CommandBasedTaskService.java:176)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445236894Z  at deployment.kie-server.war//org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.task.SynchronizedTaskService.complete(SynchronizedTaskService.java:118)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445241610Z  at deployment.kie-server.war//org.jbpm.kie.services.impl.UserTaskServiceImpl.completeAutoProgress(UserTaskServiceImpl.java:254)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445246361Z  at deployment.kie-server.war//org.kie.server.services.jbpm.UserTaskServiceBase.completeAutoProgress(UserTaskServiceBase.java:115)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445251575Z  at deployment.kie-server.war//org.kie.server.remote.rest.jbpm.UserTaskResource.complete(UserTaskResource.java:231)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445256552Z  at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor756.invoke(Unknown Source)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445261283Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445270656Z  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445275309Z  at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:138)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445280092Z  at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:535)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445284959Z  at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:424)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445290239Z  at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$0(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:385)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445296246Z  at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:356)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445301601Z  at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445306601Z  at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:356)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445311706Z  at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:329)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445316512Z  at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:440)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445321313Z  at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:229)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445326053Z  at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:135)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445332984Z  at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:356)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445338429Z  at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:138)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445343584Z  at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:215)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445371739Z  at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:227)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445377575Z  at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445382384Z  at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445392890Z  at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445398521Z  at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445403322Z  at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445408019Z  at io.opentracing.contrib.opentracing-jaxrs2//io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:52)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445413000Z  at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445417799Z  at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445422648Z  at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445427307Z  at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445448384Z  at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445453972Z  at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445459127Z  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445464497Z  at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445469617Z  at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445474471Z  at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445479398Z  at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445484350Z  at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445489821Z  at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445576349Z  at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445588359Z  at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445591564Z  at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445600918Z  at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445603591Z  at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445606040Z  at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445608648Z  at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445610986Z  at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445615132Z  at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445617575Z  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445619967Z  at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445622423Z  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445624890Z  at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445627921Z  at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445630408Z  at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445632707Z  at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445634977Z  at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445637305Z  at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445639685Z  at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445642127Z  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445644627Z  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445649521Z  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445652150Z  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445654646Z  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445657159Z  at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445659492Z  at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445662005Z  at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445664525Z  at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:370)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445666857Z  at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445669212Z  at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445671560Z  at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445674973Z  at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445677331Z  at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445679711Z  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445681869Z Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016053: Could not commit transaction.

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445684298Z  at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1299)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445686699Z  at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:126)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445689128Z  at org.jboss.jts.integration//com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:94)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445691563Z  at org.wildfly.transaction.client@1.1.9.Final//org.wildfly.transaction.client.LocalTransaction.commitAndDissociate(LocalTransaction.java:75)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445693923Z  at org.wildfly.transaction.client@1.1.9.Final//org.wildfly.transaction.client.ContextTransactionManager.commit(ContextTransactionManager.java:71)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445698844Z  at org.wildfly.transaction.client@1.1.9.Final//org.wildfly.transaction.client.LocalUserTransaction.commit(LocalUserTransaction.java:53)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445701552Z  at deployment.kie-server.war//org.drools.persistence.jta.JtaTransactionManager.commit(JtaTransactionManager.java:246)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445703830Z  ... 92 more

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445706425Z Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: IOException while storing process instance 51600: jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445708905Z  at deployment.kie-server.war//org.jbpm.persistence.processinstance.ProcessInstanceInfo.transform(ProcessInstanceInfo.java:250)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445711487Z  at deployment.kie-server.war//org.drools.persistence.TriggerUpdateTransactionSynchronization.beforeCompletion(TriggerUpdateTransactionSynchronization.java:61)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445713950Z  at deployment.kie-server.war//org.drools.persistence.jta.JtaTransactionSynchronizationAdapter.beforeCompletion(JtaTransactionSynchronizationAdapter.java:54)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445716302Z  at org.jboss.as.transactions@19.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.txn.service.internal.tsr.JCAOrderedLastSynchronizationList.beforeCompletion(JCAOrderedLastSynchronizationList.java:113)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445718724Z  at org.wildfly.transaction.client@1.1.9.Final//org.wildfly.transaction.client.AbstractTransaction.performConsumer(AbstractTransaction.java:236)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445721048Z  at org.wildfly.transaction.client@1.1.9.Final//org.wildfly.transaction.client.AbstractTransaction.performConsumer(AbstractTransaction.java:247)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445723381Z  at org.wildfly.transaction.client@1.1.9.Final//org.wildfly.transaction.client.AbstractTransaction$AssociatingSynchronization.beforeCompletion(AbstractTransaction.java:292)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445725962Z  at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:76)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445728381Z  at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:360)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445730784Z  at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:91)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445733133Z  at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:162)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445735351Z  at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1287)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445737647Z  ... 98 more

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445739684Z Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445741846Z  at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1185)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445744214Z  at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445746588Z  at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:896)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445749131Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445754049Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445756376Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445758596Z  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445760749Z  at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1130)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445762922Z  at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445765296Z  at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445767606Z  at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445769915Z  at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445772259Z  at deployment.kie-server.war//org.drools.core.marshalling.impl.SerializablePlaceholderResolverStrategy$SerializablePlaceholderStrategyContext.write(SerializablePlaceholderResolverStrategy.java:97)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445774747Z  at deployment.kie-server.war//org.drools.serialization.protobuf.PersisterHelper.writeStrategiesIndex(PersisterHelper.java:209)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445777009Z  at deployment.kie-server.war//org.drools.serialization.protobuf.PersisterHelper.writeToStreamWithHeader(PersisterHelper.java:159)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445779317Z  at deployment.kie-server.war//org.jbpm.persistence.processinstance.ProcessInstanceInfo.transform(ProcessInstanceInfo.java:244)

2023-04-29T12:46:54.445781581Z  ... 109 more

i was trying to put two user tasks continuously but when the flow enters to the second user task, the process shows an error! but if i remove the second user task and end the process there will not be any problems! there is no difference whether i try this process with a new empty user task or a full and completed parametrized user task!